# Proof verification: $f^{-1}$ is bijective with $(f^{-1})^{-1}=f$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

**Theorem.** If $f: X \to Y$ and $g: Y \to X$ are bijective maps, then the following assertions hold:

**(1)** $f^{-1}$ is bijective with $(f^{-1})^{-1}=f$

*Proof is left as an exercise.*

---

Things we already know (stated in the book)

*Definition 2.18*: Let $f: X \to Y$ and $g: Y \to Z$. Thus, $g  \circ f: X \to Z$

*Definition 2.21*: $f = g^{-1}$ and $g = f^{-1}$

---

My attempt:

$(f^{-1})^{-1}=f$

$g^{-1}=f$

$f = f$

---

> Is the proof correct? Seems so simple it makes me nervous, haha.

---

Liesen, J., Mehrmann, V. 2015. Linear Algebra. Berlin, Germany.: Springer.

Comment: Besides $f$ and $g$ being bijective, you need them to be mutual inverses.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz Forgot to mention that in the problem. That's something "we already know". I'm going to add it right away.

Comment: I assume you're looking at Theorem 2.22 from the reference, and if so this is not correct! $f$ and $g$ are not assumed to be inverses, making your argument incorrect beyond the fact that it's written backwards. Indeed, the codomain of $g$ is not assumed to equal the domain of $f$ in this theorem. See my answer below.

Comment: @NathanielMayer I think the correct procedure here is to leave the comments up, since it's easy to understand what happened by reading the comment exchange even though the post has been adjusted since. In other situations, e.g. a typo was pointed out and corrected without leaving a reply, you can mark the comment as "obsolete": see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8690/19006

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is not correct, for three reasons:

1. Your proof is kind of written "backwards". A proof should always be a finite sequence of logical steps, *starting* from what you already know to be true and *ending* with what you wanted to prove. In this problem, we already know that $f$ is a function, so we can start by saying $f = f$. It's not valid to start by saying $(f^{-1})^{-1} = f$, since this is part of what we want to prove!
2. "Things we already know: $f=g^{−1}$ and $g=f^{−1}$": **this is incorrect**! There is no assumed relationship at all between $f$ and $g$ in the statement of the theorem. You can be absolutely sure of this because if $f = g^{-1}$ were true, then we would have $g : Y \to X$, but instead the assumption is $g : Y \to Z$ (it seems you typo'd this when copying down the theorem statement), and $Z$ is not neccesarily equal to $X$. I think you're getting this from Definition 2.21, but you need to be careful about this sort of thing in math: the $f$ in that definition is an arbitrary bijection, and the $f$ in this theorem is another arbitrary bijection. There is absolutely no reason that these two $f$'s have to be the same function – indeed neither one of them is any function at all in particular.
3. You actually need to prove two separate things here: first, that $f^{-1}$ is bijective, and second that the inverse of $f^{-1}$ is $f$ (that's what is meant by "$f^{-1}$ is bijective with $(f^{-1})^{-1} = f$").

Comment: Concerning **2**. As you mentioned in the comment section of the post, I am looking at Theorem 2.22 from the book indicated. However, book's **Definition 2.21** says, long story short, that $f = g^{-1}$ and $g = f^{-1}$. Should I, first introduce, we know from Definition 2.21 that $f = g^{-1}$ and $g = f^{-1}$ and then the proof (not written backwards as I did)?

Comment: Concerning **2** (again). It is not a typo (at least from me). The book does say that $f:X \to Y$ and $g: Y \to Z$

Comment: No, to repeat what I said above: the $f$ and $g$ in Definition 2.21 have *no relationship* to the $f$ and $g$ in Theorem 2.22. There are only 26 letters in the english alphabet, and if we gave every single thing a unique name we'd run out of symbols fast! As such, the letter $f$ might represent two different objects in two different contexts. If you've done any programming, this is like how variables have scope: the scope of the $f$ and $g$ in the definition is *only* that definition, and the scope of the $f$ and $g$ in Theorem 2.22 is *only* that theorem. ...

Comment: ... Put another way, Theorem 2.22 would be *exactly* the same if we replaced every instance of $f$ by $h$ and every instance of $g$ by $i$, but then we couldn't match up the notation in the theorem with that of the definition!

Comment: Regarding the potential typo: strange! My copy says $g : Y \to Z$. Assuming $g : Y \to X$ makes the theorem much less useful, so I assume the version in your copy is a mistake. Here's what I see: https://imgur.com/K7UymTG

Comment: As a side note, I downloaded my copy just now via SpringerLink (where I have access to the text through my university library), so presumably it is as up-to-date as possible.

Comment: Regarding the image you attach, my copy is the exact same (downloaded it a few weeks ago form Springer's site). I made a typo when I published that comment the first time: $g: Y \to X$. A few seconds later it was corrected to $g: Y \to Z$, probably you were already in the page and the update wasn't visible for you.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: **Proof $f^{-1}$ is bijective.** Assume $f:A \to B$ is a bijection $\iff$ $f$ has an inverse. Let $g=f^{-1}.$ If $g:B \to A \implies f \circ g=B \land g \circ f=A$. This implies $f^{-1}$ has an inverse too, hence it is bijective.

Comment: **Proof $(f^{-1})^{-1}=f$**.

Let $Id_x : X \to X$ be the identity on $X$

$f \circ f^{-1}: A\to A$

$f^{-1} \circ f: A \to A$

Answer (score 2):

This is a pet peeve of mine: Starting with something you want to be true and then doing algebra until you reach a tautology is not a proof! That's fine in your scratch work, but your proof should do those steps backwards: Start with things you know are true, then manipulate until you get the thing you want.

Otherwise, your work looks good. It is that simple :)

Comment: On the original post I forgot to say that we are given a definition which basically states $f=g^{-1}$ and $g=f^{-1}$. That's why I jumped directly into substituting.

Comment: Yeah I got that, makes sense. You're not skipping any steps, just doing them in reverse order.